# change mapreduce output format using R

Tags: r, mapreduce, dataset, dataformat

I faced a problem.When I got the mapreduce output ,the result is {key :value} format.

For example the mapreduce output is:

```
key value

a   [111,112,114]

b   [111,122,134]

c   [125]
```

so I want to change format like this:

```
a  111

a  112

a  114

b  111

b  122

b  134

c  125
```

so I want to change format using R.How to do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to interface your mapreduce data with R? Send it to R? Read it into R and change it to what you want? Is the mapreduce output in a file? Is it in R as a character vector? Please give us more information.

Comment: @RichardScriven I save mapreduce output as tsv file.I loaded tsv file into R.So I want to use R to change format

Comment: @RichardScriven what do you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
 library(stringr)
 l1 <- lapply(str_extract_all(dat$value, "[0-9]+"), as.numeric)
 #library(stringi)
 #l1 <- lapply(stri_extract_all_regex(dat$value, "[0-9]+"), as.numeric)  #would be faster  
 data.frame(key=rep(dat$key,sapply(l1, length)), value=unlist(l1))
 #     key value
 #1   a   111
 #2   a   112
 #3   a   114
 #4   b   111
 #5   b   122
 #6   b   134
 #7   c   125
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
library(devtools)
source_gist(11380733)
cSplit(dat, "value", "[^0-9]", fixed=FALSE, direction="long")[value!="" ]
#   key value
#1:   a   111
#2:   a   112
#3:   a   114
#4:   b   111
#5:   b   122
#6:   b   134
#7:   c   125
```

#### data

```
  dat <- structure(list(key = c("a", "b", "c"), value = c("[111,112,114]", 
 "[111,122,134]", "[125]")), .Names = c("key", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```